# Spring boot @ElementCollection: Unknown column 'user_roles' in 'field list'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I have simple spring boot application, i decided to add spring security there and roles.
Here's my user class:

```
//different fields

@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserRole.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
```

and the `UserRole` enum:

```
public enum UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER, ADMIN;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

I have 2 tables

users:

```
| id | name | pasword |
----------------------
|    |      |         |
```

user_roles:

```
| user_id |  user_role |
-----------------------
|         |            |
```

When i am trying to create new user i get:

```
Unknown column 'user_roles' in 'field list'
```

I throught it should add new record also to user_roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `@Column` to specify the column name of the `userRoles` so that it matches the name of the column in the `user_roles` collection table:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserRole.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "user_role")
private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
```

The `user_roles` name that is shown in the error is probably the default column name that Hibernate tries to look for according to the default naming strategy, when the `@Column` is not specified.